# How can I remove a border on hover in dropdown content?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'd like to delete a borderline in a dropdown content inhering from an "active" dropdown button. Currently, when the page is "active" (ie it's the current page), the bottom line is for both the dropdown button and the dropdown content. I want that the bottom line appears only if the dropdown content is hover. It works when the page is not active since active properties are not transferred to dropdown-content.

```css
.tm-nav-link {
  /* color: white; */
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

#tm-main-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

#tm-main-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
#tm-main-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}


.menulink {
  display: table;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 3s;
  max-height: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="menulink nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#"><span>History</span></a>
      <a class="menulink nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#"><span>Geography/span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing a left angle bracket on a closing tag in your HTML. Are you using a good editor that shows you such issues?

Comment: And does this [corrected demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5zd4Ljqv/) display the issue you're describing? If not, please update your code so we can see what you see.

Comment: Thanks, yes. Basically, history and geography are underlined when home is hover. I want to delete that. They have to be underlined only if the mouse if over one of them.

If my mouse is nowhere, only "home" is underlined. 
If my mouse is on geography, only "home" and "geography are underlined. Not history.

Comment: Is there some reason you haven't fixed your HTML here?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.tm-nav-link {
  /* color: white; */
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-link {
text-decoration: underline;
}
#tm-main-nav .nav-item .nav-link {

  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

#tm-main-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
#tm-main-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 0px solid red;
  color: red;
}

.menulink {
  display: table;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 3s;
  max-height: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 0px solid;
}

.dropdown-content:hover span {
border-bottom: 0px solid !important;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="menulink nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#"><span>History</span></a>
      <a class="menulink nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#"><span>Geography</span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Try the below modification in your code.

```
 .tm-nav-link {
  /* color: white; */
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-link {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: thanks @isherwood. @lekythos try using `.nav-link:hover {text-decoration: underline;}` . If this satisfices your need please tick mark the answer and close the question.